# Better way to full text query across multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, performance, full-text-search, query-performance

I've got a rather large query across multiple tables and their fulltext-indices which (unsurprisingly) is rather slow:

```
SELECT t0.[Key], t0.[Nr] 
FROM dbo.[Customers_View] AS t0
 WHERE (t0.[Deleted] IS NULL)
AND (EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[Customers] AS t1 WHERE t0.[Key] = t1.[Key] AND CONTAINS(*, '"smith"'))
 OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[CustomersAddresses] AS t2 WHERE t0.[Key] = t2.[CustomerKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"smith"'))
 OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[CustomersContacts] AS t3 WHERE t0.[Key] = t3.[CustomerKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"smith"'))
 OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[CustomersPartners] AS t4 WHERE t0.[Key] = t4.[CustomerKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"smith"')))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[Customers] AS t5 WHERE t0.[Key] = t5.[Key] AND CONTAINS(*, '"munich"'))
 OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[CustomersAddresses] AS t6 WHERE t0.[Key] = t6.[CustomerKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"munich"'))
 OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[CustomersContacts] AS t7 WHERE t0.[Key] = t7.[CustomerKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"munich"'))
 OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM dbo.[CustomersPartners] AS t8 WHERE t0.[Key] = t8.[CustomerKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"munich"')))
```

Is there a good way to speed up this Kind of query? Usually it is a bit more complex, I simplyfied it to the full text part.

Maybe there is a better way to to fulltext queries across multiple tables?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how dynamic your queries are, but naturally each table needs a separate query for that table.

Assuming that you are constantly querying this 4 table group, it might be worthwhile to create an **indexed view** that included the searchable fields you need from the 4 tables into a single view.

This means the overhead of maintaining the indexed view, but may help in this case.

Of course, if you have a widely varying array of tables that might be joined, you would need to consider whether this is a good idea for you or whether you should query each table separately as you are doing.

Comment: Actually thats dead on. These four table fts are always queried together. So I might as well drop the table full text indices and create a view and one for speeding things up? Never thought of that, good idea!

Comment: Did the indexed view help your performance?  Or not?

Comment: I've proposed this fix but it is not scheduled yet. I'll update as soon as I get to it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was curious, but I understand scheduling.

Comment: @RLF What do you do when the view will have to contain left joins and SQL Server does not allow you to index views with outer joins?

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but you can only use `INNER JOIN`s for Indexed views.  And the view has to be indexed to use with Full Text Search.. Cant even use sub queries. :/